# What is the state of adoption for WSDL 2.0 and WSDL HTTP Binding?

Tags: web-services, wsdl

**1)** does anyone know something about the
    adoption rate of WSDL 2.0?

I always read that it is not widely deployed compared to WSDL 1.1 but I can't find any numbers or surveys on this.

**2)** And how relevant is the HTTP Binding
    in WSDL? How many real-world
    projects actually use it?

It has been significantly improved in the WSDL 2.0 spec but all I keep finding is that WSDL 2.0 still has a low rate of adoption.

I would really appreciate if someone could point me to any reliable source that has some concrete numbers on this.

Thanks in advance, Max

**UPDATE**: Until now the only numbers I was able to find were the number of results for specific Google queries...

[WSDL 2.0](http://www.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&q=filetype%3Awsdl+description+interface+endpoint&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) `filetype:wsdl description interface endpoint` -> 29 results

[WSDL 1.1](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=filetype%3Awsdl+definitions+porttype&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) `filetype:wsdl definitions porttype` -> About 9,100 results

EDIT: Changed the title to make the intent of the question more clear.

Comment: Well, at least this question is the first result for googleing "adoption wsdl" and the second result for "adoption wsdl 2.0"...

Comment: Is it "googling" or "googleing"? Both look silly.

Comment: Could someone explain to me, how this question got closed as opinion-based? I was explicitly asking for actual numbers and not peoples opinion about maturity, personal experiences, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it has no concrete numbers because everybody is still in the "talking about it" phase.  Even [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) has a "disputed" statement about the poor WSDL 2.0 support in SDKs.

Comment: Hey! Someone wrote! :) Yeah, I figured as much. But I still hope that someone will come up with some sort of unknown survey about the current rate of adoption in businesses or tools.

Comment: I'm going away for the weekend, so I'll award you the bounty although there are still 17h to go :)

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, remember that WSDL 1.x has like 7 yr of historical advantage and that it took 5-6 for it to reach the status of universally present and trusted. So, give WSDL 2.x another 5 yr :-) or at least till you see .NET CLR and VS supporting it - as in you make new project point to a WSDL 2.0 URL and you have C# code and buildable and runnable app. .NET 4.0 doesn't support is => another 2-3 years.

Auto-generated code is pretty much the only serious issue. Clients that just send requests and interpret result on their own (grab values from HTML tags - including AJAX) are not going to notice any diff since they don't really use WSDL.